# Alternative to Node js for Win CE

Tags: node.js, windows-ce

My requirement is run an embedded HTML\JS Web applications on a Win CE-ARM device.

We also have a Linux-ARM device for which we used Node js to run any Javascript app that also uses node modules like require,express and such.

Basically, we would like start a node server inside the device that serves HTML/JS pages as in when requested.

Since Win CE -ARM doesn't support node js and porting of node js to Win CE is an humongous task, we are looking for alternatives to node js in Win CE.

I looked up online and found very little on this front.

Basically we want to have a server running inside the device that serves html/js pages as in when requested( Imitate the node behaviour).

Is there any framework available for Win CE?

Any kind of comments or help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any frameworks that implement server-side Javascript on Windows CE (you can always serve html/js pages though, if that's what you're after).

Unless you do manage to find a third-party alternative, your options are limited to:

- [ISAPI extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269493.aspx)
- [ASP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269466.aspx) (note: not ASP.NET)

ISAPI extensions are written in C/C++, and are a comparatively primitive environment. This does not necessarily mean a *bad* environment - whether that's the case really depends on your requirements. We've used ISAPI extensions successfully in a number of products.

The ASP implementation in Windows CE is only a subset of what desktop IIS supports; the linked MSDN pages have all the details about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HTTPD WinCe webserver and to study how primitive and user unfriendly C++ ISAPI environment works, you could implement an extensible web-server in C# for example with RESTFUL webservices.
Refer to [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22794).

You can than use JQuery instead of ASP to create dynamic pages.

If you need also the browser on the device you can use the IESample bundled with WinCE.