# Serving HTML, JavaScript, CSS for an web application running on a Win CE device

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, windows-ce, serverside-javascript

I have a requirement at my work place that I have to write a web app using HTML and JS and run that app in a Win CE embedded device.

Basically I have to write a server side application and host all the html pages and render it on the device as and when it is requested.

Is there any inbuilt server in Win CE that I can use to host html and js pages ,ofcourse security is an utmost concern while hosting js in an embedded environment.
I looked at node js and that is not supported on Win CE. Is there any server side framework available to host js and html files?

Or should I use the inbuilt feature of WinCE(if its is der)

Can someone provide me some code samples to get started on this?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to Node js for Win CE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747253/alternative-to-node-js-for-win-ce)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747253/alternative-to-node-js-for-win-ce